# native voting for events of events booking plugin

Tags: plugin-events

I am using the [events booking plugin](https://www.joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/events-booking-joomla-events-registration.html) and struggle with some issues for voting.

How can I enable the native joomla 5 star rating for events, like I can use for articles?
It would also be good to use for event-categories.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could perhaps achieve this is to use the content plugins that come with Events Booking to insert category and event details into articles and then use the native article rating system on the articles.

**EB Event Plugin**

"This plugin is used to display event detail within a Joomla article"

```
{ebevent EVENT_ID}
```

**Eventbooking Category Content Plugin**

"This plugin is used to display all events from a category within an article"

```
{ebcategory ID_OF_CATEGORY}
```

For other ideas, it is probably worth asking the extension developers this question by posting your question on the [OS Solution Forums](https://www.joomdonation.com/forum/index.html) or by submitting a support request.

Comment: I already poste dit there now. sad answer was a simple: no we don't support that ... hmmm...

Comment: It is kind of a solution, but it looks very ugly indeed :D